# Benchmarking tool using twisted

Tags: python, twisted, benchmarking, apachebench

I am trying to write a web benchmarking tool base on twisted. Twisted is very fantastic asynchronous  framework for web applications. Because I get started with this framework for just two weeks, I face a problem, here is it:
When I test this benchmarking tool compare with ApacheBench, the result differs greatly on the same concurrency. Here is the result of my tool:

> python pyab.py 50000 50 http://xx.com/a.txt

```
speed:1063(q/s), worker:50, interval:7, req_made:7493, req_done:7443, req_error:0
```

And Here is the result of Apache Bench:

> ab -c 50 -n 50000 http://xx.com/a.txt

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.4.1
Server Hostname:        203.90.245.26
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /a.txt
Document Length:        6 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   6.89937 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      12501750 bytes
HTML transferred:       300042 bytes
Requests per second:    8210.27 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       6.090 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.122 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2004.62 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.8      0       4
Processing:     1    5   3.4      5     110
Waiting:        0    2   3.6      2     109
Total:          1    5   3.5      5     110

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      6
  75%      6
  80%      6
  90%      7
  95%      7
  98%      8
  99%      8
 100%    110 (longest request)
```

On the same url and concurrency, ApacheBench can go up to 8000 req/sec, while pyab only 1000 req/sec.

Here is my code(pyab.py):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor,threads
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.client import HTTPConnectionPool
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from twisted.python import log
import time, os, stat, logging, sys
from collections import Counter

logging.basicConfig(
    #filename= "/%s/log/%s.%s" % (RUN_DIR,RUN_MODULE,RUN_TIME),
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    level=logging.WARNING,
    #level=logging.DEBUG,
    stream=sys.stdout
)

#log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
observer.start()


class IgnoreBody(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, deferred, tl):
        self.deferred = deferred
        self.tl = tl

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        pass

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.deferred.callback(None)


class Pyab:

    def __init__( self, n = 50000, concurrency = 100, url='http://203.90.245.26:8080/a.txt'):
        self.n = n
        self.url = url
        self.pool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor, persistent=True)
        self.pool.maxPersistentPerHost = concurrency
        self.agent = Agent(reactor, connectTimeout = 5, pool = self.pool)
        #self.agent = Agent(reactor, connectTimeout = 5)

        self.time_start = time.time()
        self.max_worker = concurrency

        self.cnt = Counter({
            'worker' : 0 ,
            'req_made' : 0,
            'req_done' : 0,
            'req_error' : 0,
            })


    def monitor( self ):
        interval = int(time.time() - self.time_start)
        speed = 0
        if interval != 0:
            speed = int( self.cnt['req_done'] / interval )

        log.msg("speed:%d(q/s), worker:%d, interval:%d, req_made:%d, req_done:%d, req_error:%d" 
                % (speed, self.cnt['worker'], interval, self.cnt['req_made'], self.cnt['req_done'], self.cnt['req_error']), logLevel=logging.WARNING)


        reactor.callLater(1, lambda : self.monitor())

    def start( self ):
        self.keeprunning = True
        self.monitor()
        self.readMore()

    def stop( self ):
        self.keeprunning = False

    def readMore( self ):

        while self.cnt['worker'] < self.max_worker and self.cnt['req_done'] < self.n :
            self.make_request()

        if self.keeprunning and self.cnt['req_done'] < self.n:
            reactor.callLater( 0.0001, lambda: self.readMore() )
        else:
            reactor.stop()


    def make_request( self ):
        d = self.agent.request(
            'GET',
            #'http://examplexx.com/',
            #'http://example.com/',
            #'http://xa.xingcloud.com/v4/qvo/WDCXWD7500AADS-00M2B0_WD-WCAV5E38536685366?update0=ref0%2Ccor&update1=nation%2Ccn&action0=visit&_ts=1376397973636',
            #'http://203.90.245.26:8080/a.txt',
            self.url,
            Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
            None)

        self.cnt['worker'] += 1
        self.cnt['req_made'] += 1

        def cbResponse(resp):
            self.cnt['worker'] -= 1
            self.cnt['req_done'] += 1
            log.msg('response received')

            finished = Deferred()
            resp.deliverBody(IgnoreBody(finished, self))
            return finished

        def cbError(error):
            self.cnt['worker'] -= 1
            self.cnt['req_error'] += 1
            log.msg(error, logLevel=logging.ERROR)


        d.addCallback(cbResponse)
        d.addErrback(cbError)


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    if len(sys.argv) < 4:
        print "Usage: %s <n> <concurrency> <url>" % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit()

    ab = Pyab(n=int(sys.argv[1]), concurrency=int(sys.argv[2]), url=sys.argv[3])
    ab.start()
    reactor.run()
```

Is there any wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: your result text file urls point to a site that's, enough to say, not quite on topic

Comment: That's just a demo, the web server is a local webserver.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought those are download links to your results..

Comment: Always use `example.com` if you're going to use an example domain name.

Answer (score 0):

When I last used it, `ab` was known to have dozens of serious bugs.  Sometimes that would cause it to report massively inflated results.  Sometimes it would report negative results.  Sometimes it would crash.  I'd try another tool, like `httperf`, as a sanity check.

However, if your server is actually that fast, then you might have another issue.

Even if `ab` has been fixed, you're talking here about a C program versus a Python program running on CPython.  8x slower than C in Python is not actually all that bad, so I don't expect there is actually anything wrong with your program, except that it doesn't make use of `spawnProcess` and multi-core concurrency.

For starters, see if you get any better results on PyPy.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, they are really helpful. First, maybe ApacheBench give me a wrong result. I will use httperf and other benchmarking tools to verify this.  Sencod, the reason that server is so fast is because it only serves a static file which just contains a "hello". Third, when I run two instances of pyab at the same time, both of them can go up to 1000(req/sec). I will check all the clues one by one later. Again, Thank you!